# How to add Function in POST Headers

Tags: reactjs, post, header, authorization, token

The target is sending a POST request with Autorization header contains token.

It's function:

```
export function authHeader() {

    // return authorization header with jwt token
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    if (user && user.token) {
        return { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.token };
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}
```

Here is async function send to server:

```
    export async function submitToServer(values){
        try{
            let response = await fetch('http://localhost:50647/fund/submitfund', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type' :  'application/json',
                  authHeader()
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(values),
          });
          let responseJson = await response.json();
          return responseJson;

    }   catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

How can I add authHeader() to headers in POST to correctly authorize this request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`...` spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) like, `...authHeader()`. Your `authHeader` function returns an object `{ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.token }` or `{}`. What you want is to merge it to the object you attached with the `headers` key, so `...` operator is the correct tool here.

So your code will be:

```
export async function submitToServer(values) {
  try {
    let response = await fetch('http://localhost:50647/fund/submitfund', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        ...authHeader()
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(values),
    });
    let responseJson = await response.json();
    return responseJson;

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: If i have that type of object: 

 user: '{\n  "id": "2737b3da-51da-48e0-87e1-dd536444cfb3",\n  "auth_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ0ZXN0QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImp0aSI6IjQ3NDdlNzc2LWJhZGItNGE1Zi1hMTc4LTVkZjQ1MzQwYzg1OSIsImlhdCI6MTUzNDAxMDE4Niwicm9sIjoiYXBpX2FjY2VzcyIsImlkIjoiMjczN2IzZGEtNTFkYS00OGUwLTg3ZTEtZGQ1MzY0NDRjZmIzIiwibmJmIjoxNTM0MDEwMTg1LCJleHAiOjE1MzQwMzE3ODUsImlzcyI6IndlYkFwaSIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMC8ifQ.gQSVdsN38U0NXjqEQ78l6fbSVLruSlpxaQai5qJJI64",\n  "expires_in": 21600\n}'
  },

How can i ask for auth_token?

user.auth_token?